# Nested dataclass initialization

Tags: python, json, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I have a JSON object that reads:

```
j = {"id": 1, "label": "x"}
```

I have two types:

```
class BaseModel:
    def __init__(self, uuid):
        self.uuid = uuid

class Entity(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, id, label):
        super().__init__(id)
        self.name = name
```

Note how `id` is stored as `uuid` in the `BaseModel`.

I can load `Entity` from the JSON object as:

```
entity = Entity(**j)
```

I want to re-write my model leveraging `dataclass`:

```
@dataclass
class BaseModel:
    uuid = str

@dataclass
class Entity:
    name = str
```

Since my JSON object does not have the `uuid`, `entity = Entitye(**j)` on the `dataclass`-based model will throw the following error:

> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

The "ugly" solutions I can think of:

- Rename `id` to `uuid` in JSON before initialization:

  ```
  j["uuid"] = j.pop("id")
  ```
- Define both `id` and `uuid`:

  ```py
  @dataclass 
  class BaseModel:
      uuid = str

  @dataclass
  class Entity:
      id = str
      name = str

      # either use:
      uuid = id
      # or use this method
      def __post_init__(self):
          super().uuid = id
  ```

Is there any cleaner solution for this kind of object initialization in the `dataclass` realm?

Answer (score 0):

might be ruining the idea of removing the original `__init__` but how about writing a function to initialize the data class?

```
def init_entity(j):
    j["uuid"] = j.pop("id")
    return Entity(**j)
```

and in your code `entity = initEntity(j)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I guess that defeats my purpose.

Comment: how is implemented dataclass? If you want to keep the same class decorator for both then you should reimplement it by accepting parameter and make internally a case study ````isinstance```` then parameter key or add the case study internally with ````hasattribute```` then

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here might be to define a `classmethod` that acts as an alternative constructor to the dataclass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Any

@dataclass
class BaseModel:
    uuid: str


E = TypeVar('E', bound='Entity')


@dataclass
class Entity(BaseModel):
    name: str

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls: type[E], **kwargs: Any) -> E:
        return cls(kwargs['id'], kwargs['label']
```

(For the `from_json` type annotation, you'll need to use `typing.Type[E]` instead of `type[E]` if you're on python <= 3.8.)

Note that you need to use colons for your type-annotations within the main body of a dataclass, rather than the `=` operator, as you were doing.

Example usage in the interactive REPL:

```
>>> my_json_dict = {'id': 1, 'label': 'x'}
>>> Entity.from_json(**my_json_dict)
Entity(uuid=1, name='x')
```

It's again questionable how much boilerplate code this saves, however. If you find yourself doing this much work to replicate the behaviour of a non-dataclass class, it's often better just to use a non-dataclass class. Dataclasses are not the perfect solution to every problem, nor do they try to be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, while this will work, but it does not save much on the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution seems to be to use an efficient JSON serialization library that supports key remappings. There are actually *tons* of them that support this, but `dataclass-wizard` is one example of a (newer) library that supports this particular use case.

Here's an approach using an alias to `dataclasses.field()` which should be IDE friendly enough:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import json_field, fromdict, asdict


@dataclass
class BaseModel:
    uuid: int = json_field('id', all=True)


@dataclass
class Entity(BaseModel):
    name: str = json_field('label', all=True)


j = {"id": 1, "label": "x"}

# De-serialize the dictionary object into an `Entity` instance.
e = fromdict(Entity, j)

repr(e)
# Entity(uuid=1, name='x')

# Assert we get the same object when serializing the instance back to a
# JSON-serializable dict.
assert asdict(e) == j
```